# Artifactory support for C/ C++ dev

Tags: c++, git, makefile, artifactory

I want to cut down build time in a large C++ project by version controlling the libraries. This looks to be a bad idea with git, or any other VCS for that matter.

While there is to a git extension called git-lfs to manage this problem,  [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/)  or other similar tools seems to be a better approach.

Can Artifactory be used for a C++ project with Makefile based build system ?

Comment: Is it a bad idea?  We keep ours in source control - it seems to work ok.  Now I am worried I am missing something.

Comment: Keeping binaries in source control is almost always a bad idea. VCS are usually optimized for source code i. e. text that can be diffed and compressed very efficiently. Most are pretty bad with storing binaries regarding size and performance.

Comment: If you're just using git to cache your build products I don't see anything wrong there, I'd do that by (a) making the build hierarchy a separate repository a.k.a. a submodule, (b) committing tagged builds separately, without any history, and (c) doing the clone/update management directly.  But if you're on any kind of a decent system you can probably get much better results with ccache.

Answer (score 0):

Raw solution would be to use maven with native-plugin and extract-plugin. You will have to deploy your libraries and headers to maven repository. Then you may consume them through pom.XML just specifying dependencies. This solution is quite good if you want maintainable incremental builds, but implies certain efforts investments.